# Как правильно показать изображение с помощью QPixmap в QscrollArea?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qscrollarea, qpixmap

Хочу сделать так, что если изображение больше размера окна, то появлялись бы ползунки для прокрутки картинки.

Для этого я добавил изображение в `QLabel`, а `QLabel` в `QScrollArea`. 
При нажатии на кнопку ничего не отображается, но почему?

Может быть можно добавить изображение сразу в `QScrollArea`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QLabel, QScrollArea)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)

        scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.lbl)

        open_btn = QPushButton(self)
        open_btn.setText('Показать изображение')
        open_btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

    def show_image(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('cat.jpg')
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.lbl.resize(self.pixmap.width(), self.pixmap.height())
        self.lbl.resize(self.pixmap.width(), self.pixmap.height())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QLabel, QScrollArea, QGridLayout, QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl = QLabel() 

        scroll_area = QScrollArea() 
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.lbl) 
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        open_btn = QPushButton() 
        open_btn.setText('Показать изображение')
        open_btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(scroll_area, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(open_btn, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def show_image(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                      "Open Image", ".", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)")
        if fileName:
            self.pixmap = QPixmap(fileName)
            self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]